# Weird issue with radio button model

Tags: angularjs, radio-button

I'm having a hard time figuring out whats wrong with the model used for the radio buttons. When I select second radio button  the previous selection goes away.

Please help. Thanks in advance.

```
 $scope.editor = {

                descriptionEditor: {
                    name: $window.localStorage.descriptionEditor || 'markdown', // options are ['markdown','normal']
                    selected: true
                },

                setDescriptionEditorPreference: function (name) {
                    $window.localStorage.descriptionEditor = name;
                },

                sampleQueryEditor: {
                    name: $window.localStorage.sampleQueryEditor || 'markdown', // options are ['markdown','normal']
                    selected: true
                },
                setSampleQueryEditorPreference: function (name) {
                    $window.localStorage.sampleQueryEditor = name;
                }

            }
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/ShIQx3CTtbkNcfk8mlzc?p=preview

Comment: is there any reason why you not using checkbox instead

Comment: I typically use radio buttons when user has a binary choice. Checkboxes when user has multiple options to select.

Answer (score 0):

Figured out the issue. I had same `name` for all radio buttons. Changing each pair to different names fixed the issue.

ex: `name="check_normal_editor1` `name="check_normal_editor2`